# change cursor to pointer for all rows of the datatable except the last one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, google-visualization

Here is what I have done so far

```
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('report_results'));
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(d);
var swidth = screen.width;
view.setColumns([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
var cssClassNames = {'hoverTableRow': 'hover-table-row'};
var swidth = screen.width;
table.draw(view, {height: 700,width:swidth,'cssClassNames':cssClassNames});

<style>
.hover-table-row{
        color: #9a64ff;
        cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

Now I have the cursor as pointer in all rows except the last row.How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `default` cursor value for the last cell with CSS:

```
.hover-table-tow:last-child {
  cursor:default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this purely with CSS.

Add this after the .hover-table-row css

```
.hover-table-tow:last-child {
  cursor: default;
  color: #000000;
}
```

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor